Media3 Transformer increases bitrate
I wan't to encode videos using media3 transformers api, it works correctly but output bitrate bigger than input bitrate. althoug i am using the reducing frame rate, resolution, bitrate but it not works correctly, and it shows in video metada 1024x576 with 90 rotation. how can i fix that? Thanks in advance.
  val mediaItemSp = MediaItem.fromUri(testUri).buildUpon()
        .setClippingConfiguration(
            MediaItem.ClippingConfiguration.Builder()
                .setStartPositionMs(mStartPosition.toLong())
                .setEndPositionMs(mEndPosition.toLong()).build()

        ).build()
    val inputMediaItem = mediaItemSp

    val overlayef: OverlayEffect? = myOverlayEf(myContext)


    var targetBitrate: Int? = null
    var targetFrameRate: Int? = null
    var editedMediaItem = EditedMediaItem.Builder(inputMediaItem).setRemoveAudio(false)
        .build()
    var videoEncoderSettings = VideoEncoderSettings.Builder()
        .build()
    if (actualFrame != null) {
        if (actualFrame >= 30) {
            targetFrameRate = 30
        } else {
            targetFrameRate = null
        }
    }
    if (actualBitrate != null) {
        if (actualBitrate >= 2000000) {
            targetBitrate = 1800000
        }
        if (actualBitrate >= 1500000 && actualBitrate < 2000000) {
            targetBitrate = 1500000
        }

        if (actualBitrate >= 1000000 && actualBitrate < 1500000) {
            targetBitrate = 1000000
        }
        if (actualBitrate < 990000) {
            targetBitrate = null
        }
    }
    if (actualBitrate == null && actualFrame == null) {
        targetFrameRate = null
        targetBitrate = null
    }

    if (targetBitrate != null) {
        videoEncoderSettings = VideoEncoderSettings.Builder()
            .setBitrateMode(BITRATE_MODE_CBR)
            .setBitrate(targetBitrate)
            .build()
    }

    if (targetFrameRate != null) {
        if (overlayef != null && actualFrame != null) {
            editedMediaItem = EditedMediaItem.Builder(inputMediaItem).setRemoveAudio(false)
                .setEffects(
                    Effects(
                        listOf(),
                        listOf(
                            Presentation.createForWidthAndHeight(
                                576, 1024, LAYOUT_SCALE_TO_FIT
                            ),
                            overlayef,
                            FrameDropEffect.createSimpleFrameDropEffect(
                                actualFrame.toFloat(),
                                targetFrameRate.toFloat()
                            )))).build()
        }
    } else {
        if (overlayef != null && actualFrame != null) {
            editedMediaItem = EditedMediaItem.Builder(inputMediaItem).setRemoveAudio(false)
                .setEffects(
                    Effects(
                        listOf(),
                        listOf(
                            Presentation.createForWidthAndHeight(
                                576, 1024, LAYOUT_SCALE_TO_FIT
                            ),
                            overlayef,
                           ))).build()
        }
    }


    val compositionBuilder = Composition.Builder(EditedMediaItemSequence(editedMediaItem))

    Log.e("getTheVideoMData", "actual bitrate $actualBitrate")
    Log.e("getTheVideoMData", "actual frame rate $actualFrame")
    Log.e("getTheVideoMData", "target bitrate $targetBitrate")
    Log.e("getTheVideoMData", "target frame rate targetFrameRate")

`but when i add                 .setBitrateMode(BITRATE_MODE_CBR)
the log shows VideoEncoder error: format=Format(null, null, null, video/avc, avc1.4D401F, -1, null, [1024, 576, 29.97003, ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma)], [-1, -1]), colorInfo=ColorInfo(BT709, Limited range, SDR SMPTE 170M, false, 8bit Luma, 8bit Chroma) and my log getTheVideoMData
E actual bitrate 1138922
E actual frame rate 30
E target bitrate 1000000
E target frame rate 30

The provided information is not enough to diagnose the problem. What is videoEncoderSettings? What was the bitrate of the original video?

Sorry, I updated my question and added the video encoder settings, the original video's bitrate was 1.3 mbit, but with 720x1280 but with 576x1024 after transforming it raised to 1.6 mbit sometimes it can up to 2.5 mbit. i used  a lot method with video encoder settings. And actually I also checked all of the HDR modes but not worked any of them.

The bitrate calculation in your code produces a very small number (124K). This is a typical bitrate for audio, not video. The recommended bitrate for a 480p video is 2.5 Mbps and for 720p is 5 Mbps. I suspect that the transformer could override your bitrate setting.

i also used bitrate between 1000000 and 2000000 but why the input videos bitrate arount 1 mbit but the output over 2 mbit with lower resolutions?

I also modified mycode

How do you find the bitrate of the output video? What is the file size and duration?

I get the output video's  with third party apps such as MediaInfo, by the way it acutally increases the output video size with 720x1280 parameters the originial video was 7,37 mb but with 576x1024 my output raised to 11,1 mb.
